# Is it safe to render unescaped user input if no other user would ever see it?

Tags: javascript, php, security, xss

There is a web page that has a `<textarea>`.

You can type any text into that `<textarea>` and if you hit submit whatever you have typed get rendered on the screen. If you type `<script>alert('hello')</script>` and hit submit you would get that alert.

The web page **doesn't store the typed text** so your input could not get rendered on other clients (browsers of other users).

Does the described behavior introduce security risks for the web page owner or its users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the form is never submitted to the server, there are still risks with doing this. The main risk that I see here is if the input field can be populated by an external site.

Consider a hacker's site can post to your form, and pre-fill it with arbitrary javascript code.

He could send *any* JS code he likes, so that could include code that loads other external resources. Anything....

- It could completely overwrite your page design to mimic that of another site, for a phishing attack. (which means that when it's discovered your site is the one that gets blocked, and not his)
- It could use your site as a launch pad for sending spam. (ditto for getting blocked, and you really don't want to end up on a spam blacklist)
- It could leave your site apparently unchanged, but embed a malicious library that tracks the user or exploits a vulnerability on the browser. (hackers often go to great lengths to inject a JS include into a site; here you're giving them an open door for it)

The trouble with web security is that it is an *extremely* broad subject -- there are so many possible ways to get hacked and so many angles you need to cover. Ultimately the only way you can keep safe is by exercising best practices at all times; even when you don't see an immediate way for data to be expolited, you should still secure it because ultimately hackers rely on the exploits that we don't see.

Comment: How could an attacker embed a library if his/her input never gets stored?

Comment: Sure, it would only run for the duration that the individual user was on the page. The point is that the hacker could provide a link on his site (or even on another hacked site) that would post to your site. It would be posted fresh each time someone clicked his link. It wouldn't affect your own existing users; they wouldn't be clicking that link so they'd never get the hacked code. But victims of the hacker would follow the link to your site and get the hacked code. They may not realise it was your site or even know anything about you, but your site would take the blame once it was traced.

Comment: Would there be any way to prevent that without sanitizing input?

Comment: There are various techniques for preventing cross-site scripting, but if you're going to consider allowing unsanitised input, you need to be absolutely solid on those techniques. Sites like JSFiddle get away with it by having all the code run in its own iframe, isolated from the rest of the page, which does help, but you still need to lock it all down tight, and you can be sure that they do sanitise it even then.

Answer (score 4):

Since you've tagged this `php`, presumably the form is being submitted to a server side script and then the input is rendered back. This renders you vulnerable to [reflected XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Non-persistent).

```
<!-- on a third party site -->
<form action="http://example.com/your_script" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="your_field" value="attack payload">
</form>
<script>document.forms[0].submit();</script>
```

---

If that isn't the case and content is added to the page with client side JavaScript and never reads from the HTTP request, then it is still vulnerable to attacks that encourage people to "Just copy/paste this into the textarea!".

Answer (score 3):

A user may be coerced by an attacker to visit your site unexpectedly. E.g.:

```
<form action="yourserver.com/insecure_site.php">
    ...
</form>
```

This allows the attacker to inject whatever he wants into your site which the unsuspecting user is visiting.

Comment: Couldn't an attacker request /insecure_site.php anyway?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I'm saying the attacker hosts the above form on *his* site, the user visits that site, submits the form which goes to *your* site. Now the user is on your site with content injected by the attacker. The attacker achieved XSS in your site's context.

Comment: @EmanuilRusev — Then they would only be attacking themselves. The point is that the victim's browser is used to deliver the attack so the victim suffers the effects of it.

Comment: @deceze, how would the unsuspecting user be threatened if the input of the attacker is never stored?

Comment: @Emanuil You seem to be missing the key point: a `<form>` on a 3rd party site **directly submits to your site.**

Comment: @deceze, I'm confused. Can't any form submit to any web page regardless of whether it has the described behavior?

Comment: @Emanuil Yes, exactly. And by using this behaviour an attacker can inject content into a webpage the user is viewing within the context of your domain. This injected content then has full access to everything within the context your site. It could steal the user's authentication cookies for your site or make arbitrary requests on behalf of the user on your site.